# Should I use `bundle exec` or Rails' binstubs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Say I have a Rails app with gems installed with `bundler`. Should I use `bundle exec rails` or `bin/rails`? Should I use `bundle exec rake` or `bin/rake`? Is there any difference? Is any of those better then the other one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr** no particular difference, but if I were to choose, I'd use `bin/rails`

There's little to no difference. Let us see.

`DISABLE_SPRING=1 bin/rails --version`:

`bin/rails`: [`require_relative '../config/boot'`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/bin/rails.tt#L2)

`config/boot`: [`require 'bundler/setup'`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/boot.rb.tt#L3)

`bundler/setup`: [`Bundler.setup`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.16.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb#L10)

`Bundler.setup`: [`definition.validate_runtime!`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.16.5/lib/bundler.rb#L101)

`Bundler.definition`: [`Definition.build`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.16.5/lib/bundler.rb#L135)

`Bundler::Definition.build`: [`Dsl.evaluate`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.16.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb#L35)

`Bundler::Dsl.evaluate`: [`builder.eval_gemfile`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.16.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb#L12)

`Bundler::Dsl#eval_gemfile`: [`instance_eval`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.16.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb#L47)

After `require 'bundler/setup'`, trying to `gem 'rails', 'x.y.z'` results in:

> *** Gem::LoadError Exception: can't activate rails (= x.y.z), already activated rails-5.1.3. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.

With `bundle exec rails --version`, we end up running `bin/rails` anyway:

`~/.gem/ruby/x.y.z/bin/rails`: [`load Gem.activate_bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v2.7.7/lib/rubygems/installer.rb#L747)

`exe/rails`: [`require 'rails/cli'`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1/railties/exe/rails#L10)

`rails/cli`: [`Rails::AppLoader.exec_app`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1/railties/lib/rails/cli.rb#L7)

`Rails::AppLoader.exec_app`: [`exec RUBY, 'bin/rails', *ARGV](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1/railties/lib/rails/app_loader.rb#L53)

Also, do note the message one can found in the [last file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1/railties/lib/rails/app_loader.rb#L13-L14):

> Beginning in Rails 4, Rails ships with a `rails` binstub at ./bin/rails that should be used instead of the Bundler-generated `rails` binstub.

So, at the end of the day there's no difference. But considering the fact that Rails goes through the trouble of shipping its own binstubs, I'd favor `bin/rails` alternative. Also, it autocompletes better.

And,

> App executables now live in the `bin/` directory: `bin/bundle`, `bin/rails`, `bin/rake`. Run `rake rails:update:bin` to add these executables to your own app. `script/rails` is gone from new apps.
>
> Running executables within your app ensures they use your app's Ruby version and its bundled gems, and it ensures your production deployment tools only need to execute a single script. No more having to carefully `cd` to the app dir and run `bundle exec ...`.
>
> Rather than treating `bin/` as a junk drawer for generated "binstubs", bundler 1.3 adds support for generating stubs for just the executables you actually use: `bundle binstubs unicorn` generates `bin/unicorn`. Add that executable to git and version it just like any other app code.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 5):

`bundle exec` just ensures that all gems in Gemfile are installed (globally or on userspace or in `vendor/bundle` directory of the project) when running the command. It's explained in more detail in https://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html (especifically https://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html#BUNDLE-INSTALL-BINSTUBS section):

> #### Bundle Install --binstubs
>
> If you use the `--binstubs` flag in `bundle install`, Bundler will automatically create a directory (which defaults to `app_root/bin`) containing all of the executables available from gems in the bundle.
>
> After using `--binstubs`, `bin/rspec spec/my_spec.rb` is identical to
> `bundle exec rspec spec/my_spec.rb`.

Binstubs may also include other customizations like loading `spring` gem, which preloads and speeds up the Rails application.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, running from a binstub will do the same thing that `bundle exec` does, but binstubs have a few minor advantages:

- they tend to be slightly faster
- there is less to type out
- autocomplete works

They have one minor disadvantage that I can think of:

- you have to remember to generate them

For a Rails app, I'd say the big reason that binstubs are nicer is that they represent a convention for how to run local executables belonging to your app. To me they explicitly say "run THIS rails," "run THIS rspec" etc.

(In fact, you can run the binstubs from outside of the application root, and they should load the right version of the gem. But in practice they tend to e.g. fail to find config files when run that way.)

An even better reason is that spring also makes binstubs. So depending on your setup, **it's possible that your `bin/rails` actually does *more* than `bundle exec rails`, like starting spring**.

Finally, as of Rails 7 there is a convention of having a `bin/dev` file, which isn't a proper binstub but instead a script that runs foreman with your app's Procfile, and installs foreman if it doesn't exist. For me that reinforces the idea that everything should just be started from `bin`, though it won't cause problems if you don't.

Most of the time even running the naked executable name will give you the same version, it's just that when it doesn't, you may not realize what's going on.

Some more info here: https://andre.arko.net/2021/02/22/never-bundle-exec-again/

Answer (score -1):

There are no benchmarks in these answers. Using [hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) we can get a sense of how long it takes Rails to load using either option.

The tests below were performed with Ruby 3.2.0 with YJIT enabled on Rails 7. No one should rely on these benchmarks; use them as a guide to run your own benchmarks with your own Rails app to determine which script to use if performance matters.

#### `bundle exec rails --version`

```
$ hyperfine --runs 40 --warmup 10 "bundle exec rails --version"
Benchmark 1: bundle exec rails --version
  Time (mean ± σ):     487.9 ms ±  11.6 ms    [User: 305.1 ms, System: 112.3 ms]
  Range (min … max):   470.9 ms … 520.2 ms    40 runs
```

#### `bin/rails --version`

```
$ hyperfine --runs 40 --warmup 10 "bin/rails --version"
Benchmark 1: bin/rails --version
  Time (mean ± σ):     337.5 ms ±  10.5 ms    [User: 189.2 ms, System: 78.7 ms]
  Range (min … max):   317.8 ms … 372.0 ms    40 runs
```

### Winner: `bin/rails`

150ms isn't much of a difference but may matter in systems where boot time is absolutely essential.

Why is there a difference? It comes down to what each script does:

#### `bin/rails`

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path("../config/application", __dir__)
require_relative "../config/boot"
require "rails/commands"
```

#### `vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/rails`

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

Gem.use_gemdeps

version = ">= 0.a"

str = ARGV.first
if str
  str = str.b[/\A_(.*)_\z/, 1]
  if str and Gem::Version.correct?(str)
    version = str
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

if Gem.respond_to?(:activate_bin_path)
load Gem.activate_bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
else
gem "railties", version
load Gem.bin_path("railties", "rails", version)
end
```

The script used by bundler does more things and so takes longer to run. In a properly configured application either script will work properly so the only concern should be performance, if it matters.

Answer (score -2):

Bundle exec is a Bundler command.

You should use bundle exec in all the cases as it

> bundle-exec - Execute a command in the context of the bundle

More info can be found here: http://bundler.io/v1.15/bundle_exec.html

bin/rails might work but only if all the required gems/executables are present on your system without the scope of the bundle.

In short if you have all the gems installed on your system (eg. globally) the bin/rails will work (but might generate conflicts). If you however installed them only within the scope of the bundle they might not work.

`bundle exec` ensures that the gems and their versions from your Gemfile are being used.

Comment: How do I know if gem is installed globally?

Comment: @x-yuri You can execute `bundle exec gem list` to show you the gem list withing the scope of the bundle. For gems outside of bundle just exec `gem list`.

Comment: I see `rails` in the output of `bundle exec gem list`, then I downgrade `rails`  in `Gemfile` (as a result I have at least two versions of `rails` on my system, with one of them being in the bundle), and when I run `bin/rails --version`, it reports the correct one (the one in `Gemfile`). No conflicts, no nothing. How do I see the difference?

Comment: @x-yuri You can test it by installing a few different versions of the same gem. Eg `pry`.

Add to your Gemfile
`gem "pry","0.10.2"'

`bundle install`

`gem install pry --version 0.10.4`

`bundle exec gem list | grep pry`

`gem list | grep pry`

`pry --version`

should show you that there are indeed differences. (Sorry for the edit, enter sends the comment in here and i'm not used to it)

Comment: Apparently I meant difference between `bundle exec rails` and `bin/rails`. I [fail](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/9ad39f3de52a61a72306210d8103afa4) to see it.

Comment: A long time ago I upvoted this answer… Sadly, SO prevents me from undoing so. I no longer believe it be correct – especially with Rails 7 using `foreman` to start several processes at once when running `bin/dev`.